# Matplotlib - How can I animate change of line as slope and intercept change

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am fitting values to a line using linear regression using gradient decent.  At each iteration the line gets closer and closer to the best fit.

Right now I just display the final line. But I would like to illustrate how the line fits the data better and better as the iteration progress.

I looked at some sample, but they seem to be just adding new x,y points to an existing line.  With each iteration I want to remove the old line, and draw a new line with the latest data.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can replace all data in plot - there is even example on Matplotlib page: http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/examples/animation/simple_anim.html

Comment: There is [an example on how to use `FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/animate_decay.html) in matplotlib. There is no difference between adding one new value to a line or adding all new values to the line in each iteration step. So this example is perfectly valid for your case. If you have a specific problem, you should provide a [MCVE], since without any code and/or detailed explanation, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I see my error.  I started with the example furas mentioned but was misunderstanding what they were doing in the animate()

Answer (score 1):

Using the hints provided above, I created this sample code that showed me how to animate fitting in Jupyter Notebook.  It has both fixed and animated data.

```
%matplotlib notebook
# A simple example of an animated plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Initial plot
x = np.arange(0., 10., 0.2)
y = np.arange(0., 10., 0.2)
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,8)
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.xlabel("Size (sq.ft)")
plt.plot([1, 1.2, 3], [3, 3.5, 4.7], 'go', label='Training data')
#ax.plot(test_house_size, test_house_price, 'mo', label='Testing data')

def animate(i):
    print(i)    
    x = np.arange(0., 6, 0.05)
    line.set_xdata(x)  # update the data
    line.set_ydata( x ** (1 + (i/10.0)))  # update the data

    return line,


# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(y)
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.arange(1, 10), init_func=init, interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```